# From a OrderDict to a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose as a result of a loop to csv file I get the following order dict:

```
OrderedDict([('NAME', 'Apple'), ('Colour', 'red'), ('Type', 'Fruit'), ('COMMENT', 'Fuji')])
```

my csv in dataframe format

```
  NAME                 Colour             Type         COMMENT
 Apple                  red               Fruit        Fuji
 Apple                  green             Fruit        nan
```

My code to open the csv file is:

```
reader =csv.DictReader(csvfile)

record_dictionary = {}

for k,row in reader:
    print(row)
    record_dictionary = {row for row in reader if not row['COMMENT']}
```

My csv file has 4 columns and I wan to pass each column as a key value pair and the column COMMENT must not be nan. So my final result on this case would be a dictionary of key 1 with 4 key value pairs.

Why I'm I'm getting the following error when trying to actually built the dictionary?

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: key 0 , value: ('NAME': 'Apple'), ('Colour': 'red'), ('Type': 'Fruit'), ('COMMENT': 'Fuji')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never specify a key for the `dict`. Assuming by `nan`, you meant empty fields in csv. You can create a `dict` by iterating over the rows with index using `enumerate()`.

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as fileo:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fileo)

    rec = {i:row for (i,row) in enumerate(reader) if row['COMMENT'] != ''}
    print(rec)
```

test.csv

```
NAME,Colour,Type,COMMENT
 Apple,red,Fruit,Fuji
 Apple,green,Fruit,
 Apple,blue,Fruit,Kiwi
```

Output:

```
{0: OrderedDict([(' NAME', ' Apple'), ('Colour', 'red'), ('Type', 'Fruit'), ('COMMENT', 'Fuji')]), 
2: OrderedDict([(' NAME', ' Apple'), ('Colour', 'blue'), ('Type', 'Fruit'), ('COMMENT', 'Kiwi')])}
```

If you want continuous indices, you can iterate with a separate count.

Comment: thanks.. Why does dictionaries always have all types str , even if one of my columns have all numbers/integers and so on.?

Comment: As such dictionaries don't have any types by default, it takes whatever it is given. It is how `csv.DictReader()` parses the given csv file. Each field in csv is read in as a string, it is just passed onto the dictionary.

Comment: any way of changing the types?

Comment: Yes. If you know the type for sure, you can use inbuilt functions to convert the string. For example, if it's an integer, you can do `int(string)`.

Comment: yes I know all the types. For example let say the field Colour is string but I want to make become a integer which inbuild function / code I should use?

Comment: Will the `csv` contain the integer value for color as `"123"` or you want to map the color to some integer value like `"red": 1`?

Comment: yes he real data contains fields like Long and Lat ( integers) and wind speed in float.. This data i put is fictitious...TYPE                 26583 non-null object
LAT                  26583 non-null float64
LON                  26583 non-null float64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178723/discussion-between-xnkr-and-ian-de-oliveira).